# Spotify Authentication Failure using implicit grant

Tags: javascript, spotify

I am trying to authenticate with Spotify using the Implicit Grant flow outlined [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/). I have added localhost:3000 and localhost:3000/callback/ to my user dev dashboard (I've also tried various combinations of these, such as http://localhost:3000/callback, localhost:3000/callback, and just about any quirk I could think of). I am using the example provided in the Spotify tutorial on [this](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples) Github page. Here is my setup for the implicit grant authentication:

app.js:

```
/**                                                                             
 * This is an example of a basic node.js script that performs                   
 * the Implicit Grant oAuth2 flow to authenticate against                       
 * the Spotify Accounts.                                                        
 *                                                                              
 * For more information, read                                                   
 * https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit_grant_flow
 */                                                                             

var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework               
var app = express();                                                            
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                                 
console.log('Listening on 3000');                                               

app.listen(3000);
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example of the Implicit Grant flow with Spotify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
      #login, #loggedin {
        display: hidden;
      }
      .text-overflow {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 500px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="login">
        <h1>This is an example of the Implicit Grant flow</h1>
        <button id="login-button" class="btn btn-primary">Log in with Spotify</button>
      </div>
      <div id="loggedin">
        <div id="user-profile">
        </div>
        <div id="oauth">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script id="user-profile-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h1>Logged in as {{display_name}}</h1>
      <div class="media">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <img class="media-object" width="150" src="{{images.0.url}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Display name</dt><dd class="clearfix">{{display_name}}</dd>
            <dt>Id</dt><dd>{{id}}</dd>
            <dt>Email</dt><dd>{{email}}</dd>
            <dt>Spotify URI</dt><dd><a href="{{external_urls.spotify}}">{{external_urls.spotify}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Link</dt><dd><a href="{{href}}">{{href}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Profile Image</dt><dd class="clearfix"><a href="{{images.0.url}}">{{images.0.url}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Country</dt><dd>{{country}}</dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script id="oauth-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h2>oAuth info</h2>
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Access token</dt><dd class="text-overflow">{{access_token}}</dd>
      </dl>
    </script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function() {

        var stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

        /**
         * Obtains parameters from the hash of the URL
         * @return Object
         */
        function getHashParams() {
          var hashParams = {};
          var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
              q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
          while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
             hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
          }
          console.log(hashParams);
          return hashParams;
        }

        /**
         * Generates a random string containing numbers and letters
         * @param  {number} length The length of the string
         * @return {string} The generated string
         */
        function generateRandomString(length) {
          var text = '';
          var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
          }
          return text;
        };

        var userProfileSource = document.getElementById('user-profile-template').innerHTML,
            userProfileTemplate = Handlebars.compile(userProfileSource),
            userProfilePlaceholder = document.getElementById('user-profile');

            oauthSource = document.getElementById('oauth-template').innerHTML,
            oauthTemplate = Handlebars.compile(oauthSource),
            oauthPlaceholder = document.getElementById('oauth');

        var params = getHashParams();

        var access_token = params.access_token,
            state = params.state,
            storedState = localStorage.getItem(stateKey);

        console.log(access_token);
        if (access_token && (state == null || state !== storedState)) {
          console.log('reached null state or unstored state');
          alert('There was an error during the authentication');
        } else {
          localStorage.removeItem(stateKey);
          if (access_token) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
                headers: {
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                },
                success: function(response) {
                  userProfilePlaceholder.innerHTML = userProfileTemplate(response);

                  $('#login').hide();
                  $('#loggedin').show();
                }
            });
          } else {
              console.log('Second Canary');
              $('#login').show();
              $('#loggedin').hide();
          }

          document.getElementById('login-button').addEventListener('click', function() {

            var client_id = 'Not for your eyes'; // Your client id
            var redirect_uri = 'localhost:3000/callback/'; // Your redirect uri

            var state = generateRandomString(16);

            localStorage.setItem(stateKey, state);
            var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';

            var url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
            url += '?response_type=token';
            url += '&client_id=' + encodeURIComponent(client_id);
            url += '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scope);
            url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri);
            url += '&state=' + encodeURIComponent(state);
            url += '&show_dialog=true';

            console.log(url);
            window.location = url;
            console.log('clicked');
          }, false);
        }
      })();
    </script>
</html>
```

After approving my application, I return to the URI with no avail. Here is the result:
[image: Firefox Error]

In other words, I'm getting the response I'm supposed to (at least so it seems to me). But Firefox doesn't know what to do with it, and Chrome wants me to use xdg-open. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting http://127.0.0.1:3000 instead localhost:3000 on index.html? It's strange Firefox doesn't recognize "localhost"... what's your OS?

Comment: Explicitly using the loopback IP gives me an error on Spotify's authentication. I'm running Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Check if localhost is defined on /etc/hosts, it should say "127.0.0.1   localhost"

Comment: Yep, I've got that in my hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this flow working now. First, I changed my URL's on my dashboard. I now have them set to http://localhost:3000 and http://localhost:3000/callback. Then, I added a route in my app.js file:

```
app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {
   res.redirect('/');
});
```

This solved my issue and I can now authenticate properly.